# Test result window netbeans não está mostrando os testes

Tags: java, netbeans, testes, testes-de-unidade, junit

Quando eu clico com o botão direito em um projeto Maven que contém testes JUnit mostra o resultados dos testes na saída "padrão" a mesma onde sai o resultado do build. Eu quero que ele mostre os testes na janela de testes e não numa Output comum.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que acontece se executar os testes com `ALT+F6`?

Comment: mesmo resultado que clicar no botão projeto>'Test'